# Installing CentOS to a flashdrive trouble

Tags: centos, iso

I have been using `GParted` and `UNetBootin` to install `CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso` onto a flashdrive. I have partitioned the flashdrive as I have a seperate ISO installed on there. The other partition I want to have `CentOS` on has been partitioned for 2GB and has `ext3` filetype. However, when I go through the installation process, it prompts me to choose as shown below:

[image]

I looked up instructions on this and some instructions advised me to choose `vmlinuz` as the disk image, but when I do this I get:

[image]

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I suggest trying to create the stick with [**liveusb-creator**](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/).

Comment: I installed it, but I am not sure how to run it. I have tried running it in the `terminal` using `./liveusb-creator` but that doesnt work..

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: When I run it, it throws some compilation errors:          `    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files
`

Comment: I noticed that this program is used exclusively for Fedora, and I am not entirely sure if this makes a difference but I am using Ubuntu..

Comment: I am not using an RPM based system, I am using a debian based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ubuntu why not follow these steps?
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Just point to the CentOS ISO.